# Why does the factor $\sqrt{-g}$ make the volume element invariant?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, covariance

My question is an extension on [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/472725/) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252208/) question. The question is, how or "in what sense" does the factor $\sqrt{-g}$ make the measure invariant?

Suppose, I do not add this factor to the measure. This would cause the absolute value of the Jacobi determinate to appear in the integral. This seems fine to me. I can still calculate the integral. Why is the factor necessary?

Comment: Yes, you can calculate things. But then you're calculating physics of something else. In GR, the relevant symmetry is general coordinate invariance; changing coordinates should not affect physics. Not adding $\sqrt{-g}$ changes the action, and therefore physics.

Comment: $\sqrt{-g}$ ***is*** the absolute value of the determinant of the Jacobian matrix!

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63950/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @G.Smith Isn't it the square root of the absolute of the determinant?

Comment: No. See page 2 of https://www.reed.edu/physics/courses/Physics411/html/page2/files/Lecture.17.pdf.

Comment: $\det{g_{\mu\nu}}=(\det{J^\mu_\nu})^2$

Comment: @G.Smith That's my mistake; confused Jacobian and the metric tensor.

Comment: Technically you could choose a frame where that terms is just 1. For instance an everywhere oriented orthonormal frame (as in tetrad formulation); however all of the other terms in your equations would also be changed, ultimately resulting in the same action density.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You include this factor $\sqrt{-g}$ in order to make the action invariant under diffeomorphisms. If you did not include it, it would be the integral of a scalar tensor density of weight different from zero (I think +1 or -1, I don't really remember how the convention works), meaning that as you said the measure would change of a determinant factor.

By including $\sqrt{-g}$ you remove this change, since $$g=det(g_{\mu\nu})\rightarrow det\left(g_{\tau\lambda}\frac{\partial x^{\tau}}{\partial x'^{\mu}}\frac{\partial x^{\lambda}}{\partial x'^{\nu}}\right)=g\,\cdot\,(|J|^{-1})^2=g'$$
and
$$d^4x\rightarrow det\left(\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}\right)d^4x=|J|\,d^4x=d^4x'$$

So in conclusion
 $$d^4x\sqrt{-g}\quad\rightarrow\quad d^4x\sqrt{-g}|J|\cdot|J|^{-1}=d^4x\sqrt{-g}$$
and the action is invariant, provided the Lagrangian density is a scalar.